# How to overlay package window over console window

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying out Intellij as a possible replacement for Eclipse. In Eclipse I can drag the package explorer over the console window so that the package window overlays the console window. But in below setup the console window is overlaying the package window :

[image]

Can this be updated so that the package window overlays the console output window and the console output window is aligned vertically with the "files open" window? I've tried the various position/floating options for the window itself but this option does not seem to be available ?

Update : I'm trying to emulate this view structure in Eclipse :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to `Settings > Appearance`, enable option  `Widescreen tool window layout`

Here's an example, both panel have pinned/docked enable

[image: example]

Comment: please see question update, is this still not possible ?

Comment: @Adrian I see what you mean now, it is possible, see my updated answer